# Insulate a segment of code from jax tracing

Tags: jax

Apologies in advance for how vague this question is (unfortunately I don't know enough about how jax tracing works to phrase it more precisely), but: Is there a way to completely insulate a function or code block from jax tracing?

For context, I have a function of the form:

```
def f(x, y):
   z = h(y)
   return g(x, z)
```

Essentially, I want to call `g(x, z)`, and treat `z` as a constant when doing any jax transformations. However, setting up the argument `z` is very awkward, so the helper function `h` is used to transform an easier-to-specify input `y` into the format required by `g`. What I'd like is for jax to treat `h` as a non-traceable black box, so that doing `jit(lambda x: f(x, y0))` for a particular `y0` is the same as first computing `z0 = h(y0)` with `numpy`, then doing `jit(lambda x: g(x, z0))` (and similar with `grad` or whatever other function transformations).

In my code, I've already written `h` to only use standard `numpy` (which I thought might lead to black-box behaviour), but the compile time of `jit(lambda x: f(x, y0))` is noticeably longer than the compile time of `jit(lambda x: g(x, z0))` for `z0 = h(y0)`. I have a feeling the compile time may have something to do with jax tracing the many loops in `h`, though I'm not sure.

Some additional notes:

- Writing `h` in a jax-friendly way would be awkward (input formatting is ragged, tons of looping/conditionals, output shape dependent on input value, etc) and ultimately more trouble than it's worth as the function is extremely cheap to execute, and I don't ever need to differentiate it (the input data is integer-based).

Thoughts?

Edit addition for clarity: I know there are maybe ways around this if, e.g. `f` is a top-level function. In this case it isn't such a big deal to get the user to call `h` first to "pre-compile" the jax-friendly inputs to `g`, then freely perform whatever jax transformations they want to `lambda x: g(x, z0)`. However, I'm imagining cases in which we have many functions that we want to chain together, that have the same structure as `f`, where there are some jax-unfriendly inputs/computations, but these inputs will always be treated as constant to the jax part of the computation. In principle one could always pull out these pre-computations to set up the jax stuff, but this seems difficult if we have a non-trivial collection of functions of this type that will be calling each other.

Is there some way to control how `f` gets traced, so that while tracing it knows to just evaluate `z=h(y)` (instead of tracing `h`) then continue with tracing `g(x, z)`?

Comment: I'll add: I thought maybe making the function a jax primitive in some way might work?

Answer (score 0):

```
f_jitted = jax.jit(f, static_argnums=1)
```

static_argnums parameter probably could help

https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html

> You can use transformation parameters such as `static_argnums` for `jit` to avoid tracing particular arguments of transformed functions, though at the cost of more recompiles.